# I want my bot to @ a user but i cant get it to work

Tags: python, discord.py

Some time ago i started building a discord bot and i want that bot to punch someone by sending the message that they have been punched and this is supposed to @ them
I searched a lot on the internet and it seems like i am the only one who has that problem

This is my code but i can't get it to work  (i know that the 'user' just typed like that wont work but i tried all i can and i just can't make it work)

```
@bot.command()
async def punch(ctx, user: discord.User,):
    await ctx.send ("user has been punched")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `user.mention` to mention the user (<@user.id> would also work)
So your code would look something like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def punch(ctx, user: discord.User,):
    await ctx.send (f"{user.mention} has been punched")
```

Comment: Thx a lot that worked as i wanted it to :)